# Why does the glide and picasso won't load the url image in Google Maps Marker?

Tags: android, picasso, android-glide, android-bitmap

I am trying to load the image to my CircleImageView from a custom marker layout that I made. I tried to use glide or picasso but non of them works it is only showing the placeholder image of the marker. Can someone help me with this one. I am stuck for about 4hrs in this and still dont find what was causing this.

```
place2 = new MarkerOptions()
         .position(storeLatLng)
         .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createCustomMarker(CheckOutActivity.this , storeIMG, storeName))).title(storeClass);


...

private static Bitmap createCustomMarker(Context context, final String resource, String name) {

        View marker = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.bitmap_google_marker_layout_item, null);
        de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView image = (de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView) marker.findViewById(R.id.user_dp);
        TextView txt_name = (TextView) marker.findViewById(R.id.name);
        txt_name.setText(name);
        
        //Glide.with(marker).load(resource).apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.mipmap.loader)).into(image);
        Picasso.get()
                .load(resource)
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.loader)
                .error(R.drawable.error)
                .into(image);

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        marker.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(52, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        marker.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
        marker.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
        marker.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(marker.getMeasuredWidth(), marker.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        marker.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

**Here Is the sample image of the result**

[image: Image of the Marker]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Picasso` or `Glid` loads image asynchronously. At the time you are creating bitmap from view the `ImageView` have only placeholder(`Picasso` or `Glid` didn't download and set the image to the ImageView yet). So you can seeing placeholder in Marker. Once you have created `Bitmap` form View , anything change in the `View` later will not affect the bitmap.

To make Marker with the actual image you have to update or recreate marker again after `Picasso` download and set the Image in the `ImageView`.

I think it's better to make `Marker` with placeholder and update the `Marker` after downloading the Image.

Comment: Thank you so much! But how can i do that sir?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `Picasso` downloader -

```
Picasso.get().load(uri)
             .resize(50, 50)
             .into(new com.squareup.picasso.Target() {
                   @Override
                   public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                                    //Use bitmap for Marker
                  }
                  @Override
                  public void onBitmapFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                  }
             });
```